# Is it possible and/or advisable to generate tests dynamically in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

One trick I have found very handy in rails application programming is that `class_eval` can be used to create methods on the fly.  I'm starting to get into testing now and I wonder if a similar idea could be used to generate tests.

For example, I have a `before_filter` to require a user to be logged in for all of the actions in a controller.  I would like to write tests which ensure that the `before_filter` is being applied for all actions.  Instead of writing out each test individually I would like to instead generate all of these test automatically.

Is this type of testing advisable, or should I just stick to writing the tests out individually?  If it is, how would one go about doing so?

EDIT: This might look something like:

```
actions = {:index => :get,:show => :get,:edit => :get,:update => :put}
actions.each_pair do |action,type|
  class_eval(%Q{def test_user_required_for_#{action}
      set_active_user users(:one)
      #{type} :#{action}
      assert flash[:error]
      assert_redirected_to :action => :index
    end
  })
end
```

Now that people have verified this could be useful, where would I put a block of code such as this so that it will get executed once and only once to create these tests?

Comment: Try not to use the string form of `class_eval`. If you *must* use `class_eval` (which should not be necessary often), use the block form. It's safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DRY principle applies to test code just as much as it applies to application code.

Having one method to generate all of those tests should make it easier to verify that the test is correct in the first place.

To answer the comment (note: I haven't written Rails test code in a while, so it probably isn't 100% correct). Everything between `%| |` is one big string:

```
MyControllerTest

  [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy].each do |action|
      class_eval do %|
        test "#{action} requires before filter" do
          #test #{action} code here
        end
      |
  end

end
```

Comment: How/where would one go about creating these tests then?

Comment: Where could you put this code so that it gets executed once and only once to setup these test?

Comment: This belongs in your whichever controller you want to test. For example, if you wanted to make sure the AccountsController is locked down, the code would go in the accounts_controller_test.rb file.

Comment: Ok, great that works!  I had been trying to write a constructor and put it in there, but you are right you just have to throw it straight into the class, not a separate method call.  Thanks!

Comment: Downvoting for use of `class_eval` with a string. `*_eval` with a string is almost never necessary in Ruby, and is to be avoided as unsafe. `class_eval` with a block is much better. (In RSpec, you wouldn't need the `class_eval` at all.) I'd also disagree that DRY applies to test code as much as to application code. While I try to remove duplication in test code, I think it's more important that tests be readable, so my duplication threshold is higher for test code than application code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use `class_eval` when using `test` DSL!

```rb
class MyControllerTest
  [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy].each do |action|
    test "#{action} requires before filter" do
      #test #{action} code here
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, write your tests individually. However, if you have a bunch of identical tests, I see nothing wrong with generating each one from an `each` block such as you have.

Bonus tip: use RSpec, not Test::Unit. Besides being generally nicer, it makes what you're doing a whole lot easier.

Comment: ease of use for rspec vs test-unit is very much a matter of personal taste. I personally find test::unit (+ shoulda) much easier and more "natural" for the way that I think. this is a YMMV topic :)

Comment: @TarynEast I no longer really believe that this is a matter of taste: RSpec's `should` syntax encourages you to think about behavior, while Test::Unit's `assert` syntax encourages you to think about implementation. Generally, behavior, not implementation, is what should be tested, because we are only interested in verifying that the *interface* works as we intend it to. If you find Test::Unit more natural, that probably means you're trying to test implementation -- that is, you're trying to test the wrong thing.

Comment: @TarynEast I just reread and noticed that you're using Shoulda, so you get some of the `should` syntax. Why not just use RSpec, then? What do you like better about Shoulda?

Comment: Ability to define new asserts as a simple new method, rather than having to create entire new class of matcher.

Comment: @TarynEast I'll look at that; interesting. I have to admit, though, that after almost 5 years of using RSpec, I just created a custom matcher last month for the very first time, so this isn't something I do often. My impression has for the most part been that while Shoulda has a few cool features, it is mostly an inferior knockoff of RSpec.

Comment: Yes - that used to be my opinion too... but that changed.
I do a *lot* of meta-programming, and rspec really feels very clunky for that. As I said originally - it really depends on your taste, and what you need to get out of the tool. rspec works just fine when you're doing just exactly what rspec does well... but if you need anything else, I find it harder to modify. Test::Unit doesn't make the same kinds of assumptions - and can be easily extended. And with shoulda, you are still just as easily able to do the BDD-style tests. shoulda's come a long way in five years too. :)

Comment: @TarynEast Doubly interesting. The last time I checked Shoulda's website (a few months ago), it seemed to say that even its creators had abandoned it and were now recommending RSpec. I don't see that statement now, though. As for metaprogramming...I do a lot of that too, but my tests often don't reflect it, because I think it's an implementation issue, and I believe that only the interface should be tested. So I'm not sure how RSpec fails here.

Comment: I'm sure that I *could* do everything I need in rspec... just as you could do everything you need in Test::Unit. :)
There's nothing missing from either one.

I just find the way you think in rspec is different to the way I think naturally... and both ways "work" - so I prefer using T::U

I've tried both (and commercially not just tinkered). I really do have a preference for T::U over rspec. I am quite comfortable with BDD. I don't "just not get" rspec... I just don't prefer the way it solves problems to the way I'd do it in T::U. :)

Comment: @TarynEast Are you talking about Test::Unit with or without Shoulda? If the former, it seems to be much like RSpec; the differences are in detail. If the latter, I believe that approach is actually broken, because of what I said earlier about focusing on implementation (so I don't agree that "both ways 'work'", as you said). I don't think it's a question of personal preference.

Comment: I am, as I have always been, talking about it with shoulda. :)

Comment: @TarynEast That's what I thought, but your previous comment slightly confused me. :)