# Find HTML verb for actions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is there a way to look up the HTML for a given controller action? For example, I would like to be able to associate GET with index and PUT with update.  I want to be able to do this dynamically based on the routes.

I can get the action methods for each controller using Controller.action_methods, but this returns a set of strings of action methods.  Ideally what I would like is a hash of the form: `{:action => :verb}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:method` is part of a `:conditions` hash you can pass in to `map.connect`

```
  map.connect 'post/:id', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'create_comment',
              :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

Comment: I'm looking to essentially query the map to find the method for an action.  So in your example I would like to be able to start with "create_comment" and have a way to find :post.

Answer (score 2):

Read the rake routes task, that will provide insight:

e.g:

```
users GET    /users(.:format)     {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
```

I assume this is what you are after?

Comment: That is the data I'm looking for indeed, but now how I want to get it.  I'm trying to generate simple test cases for all of my actions which require user authentication.  See my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137589/is-it-possible-and-or-advisable-to-generate-tests-dynamically-in-rails .  I'm trying to query the Controller for it's actions and find what verb they are associated to produce the actions variable in that example.

Comment: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/routes.rake

Comment: @BryanWard I had the same problem as you - finally a real answer below (only two years later // using rails 3.2+)

Answer (score 0):

To provide a useful object with all controllers, actions, and associated verbs

```
def all_routes
    @all_routes ||= Rails.application.routes.routes.map do |route|
          { alias: route.name,
            path: route.path.spec.to_s,
            controller: route.defaults[:controller],
            action: route.defaults[:action],
            verb: route.verb.source.to_s.delete('$'+'^')
          }
    end
end
```